# Как сделать абсолютно уникальные числав с таким кодом

Tags: c#, windows

```
int g = 0;
int b = 0;


int[] number = new int[10];
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
{
    //J:
    if (i % 2 != 0)
    {
        Hg:
        number[i] = random.Next(1, 25);
        if (number[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            goto Hg;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(number[i]);
                                
    }
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        Gh:
        number[i] = random.Next(1 , 25);
        if (number[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            goto Gh;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(number[i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: "Если в массиве число уже есть, то генерирует повторно, ну а если нет, добавляем в массив", вот вам и будет "абсолютно уникальные" А вообще, ооочень странный код, где тонны дублирования, да еще и `goto`...

Comment: или взять ряд чисел, например с увеличением на 1 и случайно перемешать

Comment: А если там миллионы? Была бы такая функция которая не повторялась бы в пределах int32

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо 10 случайных числел от 1 до 25 без повторений? Можно просто их все сгенерировать и перемешать, пример

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] number = Enumerable.Range(1, 25).OrderBy(x=>random.Next()).Take(10).ToArray();
```